# Edit the way a text file is read and or written into a CSV file in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, csv, plsql

I am trying to convert a `.txt` file into a `.csv` file. This I believe I have succeeded my question is when it comes to the `.csv` file is there a way to change the formatting? the text file is below:

```
Price, cheap, good value, reasonable price, great for the price, very cheap, not pricey, affordable
Cleanliness, clean place, clean, very clean, good hygiene, good cleanliness, clean surroundings
Location, great location, nice location, great view, nice view, safe, very safe location
```

There are 3 lines that each start with the title of the category (Price, Cleanliness, Location). after that are "seed words." is it possible to change the category names into a number and have all the "seed words" in one column?

The code I have below is what I used to read the txt file into a csv file.

```
create directory FILE_READ_WRITE as 'C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\SQL HOME WORK';

DECLARE 
 fh UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE; 
 GetLinePrice Varchar2(255);
 GetLineClean Varchar2(255);
 GetLineLoc Varchar2(255);
 BEGIN fh := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('FILE_READ_WRITE', 'seed.txt', 'r'); 
 IF UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(fh) THEN  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('File read open'); 
 ELSE  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('File read not open'); 
 END IF; 
 UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(fh,GetLinePrice); 
  UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(fh,GetLineClean); 
   UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(fh,GetLineLoc); 
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Value read: '||GetLinePrice);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Value read: '||GetLineClean);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Value read: '||GetLineLoc);
 UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fh);
BEGIN
fh := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('FILE_READ_WRITE', 'seed.csv', 'w');
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(fh,GetLinePrice); 
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(fh,GetLineClean); 
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(fh,GetLineLoc); 
UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fh);
EXCEPTION  
WHEN 
OTHERS THEN  
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);END;
END;
```

My results were a CSV file that has 3 rows and looks almost exactly like the txt file except instead of the words being separated by "," they are in their own box.

Comment: I wouldn't use a database for this, as your final result is just another file (outside of a database).  Do you have access to a programming language such as Java, C#, or Python?

Comment: This is a homework assignment and the goal is to have a CSV file formatted as described above. When i add to the CSV file it should add to the table in the database as well. I do have access to java however i feel like i have gotten further with this assignment using SQL.

Comment: Why have you retagged SQL Server if you using Oracle?

Comment: I am new to posting on this forum and i thought i edited the tag out, i hope its fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You need nothing but to replace those `commas` to `semi-colons` by using

> **replace(** GetLinePrice **,',',';')**, **replace(** GetLineClean **,',',';')** and
>   **replace(** GetLineLoc **,',',';')**

during the time of writing the lines to the file :

```
DECLARE
  fh           UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  GetLinePrice Varchar2(255);
  GetLineClean Varchar2(255);
  GetLineLoc   Varchar2(255);
BEGIN
  fh := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('FILE_READ_WRITE', 'seed.txt', 'r');
  IF UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(fh) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('File read open');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('File read not open');
  END IF;
  UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(fh, GetLinePrice);
  UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(fh, GetLineClean);
  UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(fh, GetLineLoc);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Value read: ' || GetLinePrice);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Value read: ' || GetLineClean);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Value read: ' || GetLineLoc);
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fh);
  BEGIN
    fh := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('FILE_READ_WRITE', 'seed.csv', 'w');
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(fh, replace(GetLinePrice,',',';'));
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(fh, replace(GetLineClean,',',';'));
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(fh, replace(GetLineLoc,',',';'));
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fh);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
  END;
END;
```